# Creating attendance table result with PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, sql

I'd like to create a HTML table of attendance.

I have 2 SQL tables: one with a list of people with their data and the other with dates.

Table "clients" with clients looks like this:

```
cl_id | cl_name
---------------
1     | john
2     | rob
3     | sam
```

Table "absence" with dates looks like this:

```
ab_id | ab_cl_id | ab_date    | ab_type
---------------------------------------
1     | 1        | 2020-02-01 | A
2     | 2        | 2020-02-01 | P
3     | 1        | 2020-02-02 | P
4     | 2        | 2020-02-02 | P
5     | 3        | 2020-02-02 | P
6     | 2        | 2020-02-03 | A
7     | 3        | 2020-02-03 | A
```

I want this result (1, 2, 3 is days in month):

```
name | 1 | 2 | 3 
-----------------
john | A | P |
rob  | P | P | A
sam  |   | P | A
```

I tried it with this SQL:

```
SELECT     cl.cl_id, cl.cl_name, ab.cl_id, ab.ab_date, ab.ab_type
FROM       clients AS cl
INNER JOIN absence AS ab ON cl.cl_id = ab.ab_cl_id
WHERE      YEAR(ab.ab_date) = 2020
AND        MONTH(ab.ab_date) = 2
ORDER BY   cl.cl_name ASC
```

But the result is as follows:

```
name | 1 | 2 | 3 
-----------------
john | A |   |
john |   | P |
rob  | P |   |
rob  |   | P |
rob  |   |   | A
sam  |   | P |
sam  |   |   | A
```

How can I achieve the result I mentioned above?

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aggregation to reduce the number of rows.  So:

```
SELECT cl.cl_id, cl.cl_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(ab.ab_date) = 1 THEN ab.ab_type END) as day_01,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(ab.ab_date) = 2 THEN ab.ab_type END) as day_02,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(ab.ab_date) = 3 THEN ab.ab_type END) as day_03
FROM clients cl JOIN
     absence ab
     ON cl.cl_id = ab.ab_cl_id
WHERE YEAR(ab.ab_date) = 2020 AND MONTH(ab.ab_date) = 2
ORDER BY cl.cl_id, cl.cl_name ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me. I just have "a cosmetic question". I would like to ask if you can reduce the rows of days in some way (now my SQL has 31 lines, which doesn't look good). Thank you!

Comment: @ametyst . . . If you are doing this for 31 days in a month, then it is hard to reduce the size of the query and maintain readability.